# How to disable return key in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I disable the return key if the TextInput is empty.Like in default ios messenger

[image: Disabled]

[image: Enabled]

So if there is no text in the input the search button is disabled.

In react-native using `returnKeyType="search"` the Search button comes but I didn't find anything to disable it.

How will I achieve that??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [enablesReturnKeyAutomatically](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#enablesreturnkeyautomatically) props of `TextInput`

Comment: this only works on iOS. :/